# ExtJS4: How to define DnD object method in DnD plugin

Tags: javascript, extjs, drag-and-drop, extjs4

I am working on a page with **Drag from Grid to Tree** and using gridviewdragdrop and treeviewdragdrop plugin.

Everything works fine, but I don't really need to drag node, just need get the dragdata and dropdata, so I want to **stop the drop action**.

I found *notifyDrop* method in Ext.dd.DropTarget but don't know how to define that in plugin config. Anyone help? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

you can use the `beforedrop` event, do your thing and at the end of the event just `return false;` in there, that way you will not complete the drop, that's what I do to a special case that I have.